# How to get cell value of a row based on the column name of jQuery datatable?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatable

I was working on a datatable dynamically generated using jQuery and json. Now I have a delete button at the end of each row.

When I click on the delete button I want that particular row cell value based on column name which I will provide. Let's say "Sr No". I tried using column-selector:

```
var tr=$(this).closest('tr');
var table=$("#table1").DataTable();
table.column( 'Sr No:name' ).data();
```

Using the above I get data of all rows. But what I want is only for a specific row pointed by the tr object above. Now I don't know how to get the cell value.

Comment: add relevant code in the OP like html structure

Comment: there is no static html code..the datatable is generated dynamically..using json

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class name to the cells or you can use the cell index.

```
$('#table').find(".classOfTheCell").html();
$('#row').find('td:eq(0)').html();
```

You can also get the row with

```
$(this).closest('tr')
```

Comment: actually there is no class for the cell..its just a normal table td.